# Using .htaccess redirect php url to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently make subdomain for my VPS, I want redirect .php in URL

> http://bn.domain.com/forum/register.php

I'd like them to be redirected to the appropriate URL:

> http://bn.domain.com/anonpanel/

How can I do that?

> [Wed Jun 04 20:10:57 2014] [alert] [client 202.62.25.9]
>   /var/www/forum/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps
>   misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration [Wed Jun 04 20:11:01 2014] [alert] [client 202.62.25.9]
>   /var/www/forum/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps
>   misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration [Wed Jun 04 20:13:01 2014] [alert] [client 114.79.13.26]
>   /var/www/forum/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps
>   misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration [Wed Jun 04 20:13:03 2014] [alert] [client 114.79.13.26]
>   /var/www/forum/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps
>   misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration

Comment: Not clear, can you try to clarify your requirement again.

Comment: just redirect domain.com/forum/register.php to domain.com/anonpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/forum/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bn\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /register\.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /anonpanel [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: i got internal server error when using htaccess, btw not domain.com but bn.domain.com

Comment: Are you sure `mod_rewrite` is turned on? Check your Apache error.log for reason of 500 error.

Comment: That log means `mod_rewrite` is not enabled. You need to enable it in Apache server.

Comment: im already update AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, and restart apache2 service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55083/discussion-between-anubhava-and-putra-fajar-hasanuddin).

Comment: I am not server admin but `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'` means it is not enabled.

Comment: Did you place it in `/forum/.htaccess` or in root .htaccess?